# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'surprise'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-science

I have installed scikit-surprise in Windows10.

```
C:\Users\Cosmos Lord>pip install scikit-surprise
```

> Requirement already satisfied: scikit-surprise in c:\users\cosmos
>   lord\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (1.1.0) Requirement
>   already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\cosmos
>   lord\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from
>   scikit-surprise) (0.14.0) Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.2
>   in c:\users\cosmos lord\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages
>   (from scikit-surprise) (1.17.2) Requirement already satisfied:
>   scipy>=1.0.0 in c:\users\cosmos
>   lord\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from
>   scikit-surprise) (1.3.1) Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in
>   c:\users\cosmos lord\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages
>   (from scikit-surprise) (1.12.0)

But I am still unable to import surprise module.

In Spyder3 kernel, the following error is shown:

```
import surprise
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import surprise
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'surprise'

Whereas in IDLE(Python-32 bit), the following error is shown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Cosmos
>   Lord/Documents/Flask Projects/New folder/aaa.py", line 1, in 
>       import surprise   File "C:\Users\Cosmos Lord\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\surprise__init__.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       from .prediction_algorithms import AlgoBase   File "C:\Users\Cosmos
>   Lord\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\surprise\prediction_algorithms__init__.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from .algo_base import AlgoBase   File "C:\Users\Cosmos Lord\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\surprise\prediction_algorithms\algo_base.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       from .. import similarities as sims ImportError: cannot import name 'similarities' from 'surprise' (C:\Users\Cosmos
>   Lord\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\surprise__init__.py)

How do I import surprise? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

From within Spyder kernel (console), run `pip install surprise`

Then restart the kernel.

It solved the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
pip install numpy
pip install scikit-surprise
```

if your problem didn't solve, then use conda forge:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise
```

Comment: "conda install -c conda-forge scikit-surprise" worked for me. pip did not succeed as it was asking for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow

Surprise uses Cython, which requires a C compiler to be installed on the system.

More about [Cython](https://cython.org)

Installing Visual studio C++2014 could sovle this issue.
Try installing Visual Studio on your machine.

Comment: I have Visual studio C++14.0 Built-in tools

Without it, I would not be able to install scikit-surprise because it requires Visual C++14.0 Built-in tools.

Comment: I didn't understand what you just said. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Before i install scikit-surprise, I did not have Visual C++14.0 built-in tools. So when I tried to install using the following command in the command prompt
pip install scikit-surprise
it displayed an error and suggested to install visual C++14.0 built-in tools. 
After installing Visual C++14.0 built-in tools, i was able to install scikit-surprise.

Regarding the Cython, i have installed that too. 
C:\Users\Cosmos Lord>pip install Cython
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in c:\users\cosmos lord\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (0.29.13)

Comment: perfect. Congratulations. if this answer helped you then mark it is as answer

Comment: however i do have Cython . I am not able to import surprise

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your current working environment and the environment the `surprise` module has been installed into are different.

Answer (score -2):

If you are sure that you are in the right env, kindly change your IDE. I changed mine to Jupyterlab and everything started working correctly.